# PHP Regex - Get Order ID (8 digits long, starts with 0) within a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following string

`ORDER/07656473/STATUS`

where by `07656473` is the Order reference within my shop.

I currently have a function that pulls the Order reference out from said string like so

```
public function getOrderReference()
{
  $regex = '/ORDER\/([0-9]{8})\/STATUS/';

  if (preg_match($regex, $this->string, $output)) {
    return $output[1];
  }

  return false;
}
```

Which right now successfully gets the Order reference based on it being numbers only, 8 numbers long and between `ORDER` and `STATUS`.

However I need to be able to add into the regex that the reference should always start with a 0.
How can I achieve this?

I had looked at something like this `STATUS\/(0)([0-9]{7})\/ACCEPTED`
But it then splits the order reference in parts (0 and then 7656473) where as I need it to keep it as a whole.

Comment: So don’t break apart the grouping braces then, just put the 0 before the character class: `(0[0-9]{7})`

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. So simple. If you wanted to add this as an answer i'll mark as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I had looked at something like this `STATUS\/(0)([0-9]{7})\/ACCEPTED` But it then splits the order reference in parts (0 and then 7656473) where as I need it to keep it as a whole.

Then just don’t split the round braces, that group the matched results, into two sets. Keep it *one* group, and just move the `0` before the character class:

`STATUS\/(0[0-9]{7})\/ACCEPTED`